# How to select rows based on join on two columns of same table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, self-join

Sorry if the title isn't really understandable, feel free to edit it.
I have a table named CLIENT, here is a sample of the data:

```
ID_CLIENT   CLIENT_NAME     OTHER_ID    
----------------------------------------
1           'COMPANY A'     1   
2           'COMPANY B'     4
3           'COMPANY C'     3   
4           'COMPANY D'     1
```

I would like to create a query which get the CLIENT_NAME instead of the OTHER_ID.
It is really hard to explain, here is the result I would like to see with my query:

```
ID_CLIENT   CLIENT_NAME     CLIENT_BRANCH
--------------------------------------------
1           'COMPANY A'     'COMPANY A' 
2           'COMPANY B'     'COMPANY D'
3           'COMPANY C'     'COMPANY C' 
4           'COMPANY D'     'COMPANY A'
```

I would like to "link" OTHER_ID to the related CLIENT_NAME...
Feel free to edit the question if you know how to explain it better than me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have edited the topic title. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SELF JOIN** will resolve your issue.

Try this:

```
SELECT C1.ID_CLIENT, C1.CLIENT_NAME, C2.CLIENT_NAME CLIENT_BRANCH 
FROM CLIENT C1 
INNER JOIN CLIENT C2 ON C1.OTHER_ID = C2.ID_CLIENT;
```

**EDIT**

If you have `NULL` value in `OTHER_ID` column then use **LEFT JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT C1.ID_CLIENT, C1.CLIENT_NAME, C2.CLIENT_NAME CLIENT_BRANCH 
FROM CLIENT C1 
LEFT JOIN CLIENT C2 ON C1.OTHER_ID = C2.ID_CLIENT;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. But what if I have a null value in the OTHER_ID field, does it will work ?

Comment: No, if values are NULL, then the current query won't work. Since, NULL is a three valued logic. You need to use an `outer join` to include the rows. Or, provide a logic how to handle NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.client_id, a.client_name, b.client_name as client_branch
from client a join client b on (a.other_id = b.client_id)
```

(seems that I have been too late, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     a.id_client, 
           a.client_name, 
           b.client_name AS "client_branch" 
FROM       client a 
INNER JOIN client b 
ON        (a.other_id = b.id_client)
/
```

Read the documentation about [JOINS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046). Few examples from the doc on [SELF JOINS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702).

**EDIT : Regarding NULL values**

In the same link about JOINS, read about `OUTER JOINS`. Since, `NULL` is a three valued logic, it is neither equal to NULL nor not equal to NULL. You need to use an `outer join` to include the rows which doesn't match in case of NULL. Or, provide a logic how to handle NULL values.